# C++ Builder or Delphi, use RestClient and RestRequest for POST

Tags: c++, delphi

C++ Builder or Delphi.
I need to send POST to a URL, I insert a RestClient and RestRequest component, in the Client I indicate the URL, in the Resquest the parameters, but the documentation of the URL tells me to send POST "portatil/status", where I indicate that parameter to the POST? I have tested URL + "portatil/status" but it tells me the page does not exist.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing more information.  What does your code look like?  Is the "portatil/status" the route or the parameter?

Comment: I do not think it is a parameter because it indicates that it has two, the language and the number of the laptop, which I passed as parameters to the RestRequest, and the host to RestClient, the documentation says verbatim:
POST /portatil/status
Host: http: // IP: 8887
I have tried to put http: // IP: 8887 / portatil / status but it tells me page not found.

Comment: It depends on what kind these parameters have. See `TRESTRequestParameterKind` for your options. The API documentation should mention which one it expects.

Comment: How put example code here with format? i have example with kotlin, Could it help to put that code here?

Comment: A link to the API documentation would be helpful.

Comment: Your tags and post say Delphi and C++.  First, you really need to pick a language.  Second, you need to post the code that is failing for you in that language.  If you're trying this in Delphi, you need to edit your post to include your Delphi code, not Kotlin code.  You can format it in editing of the post.  You need to show us what you've tried and what error you're getting.

Comment: I have uploaded what I currently have, example in kotlin, api screens, generated from the terminal, and an extract with openapi, thanks
[link] https://mega.nz/file/uCo1zQTL#3znlEsC_vRaU5Itq2jS6c-5ptQedFViYeE946Qwv_LE [link]

Answer (score 1):

I can only give Delphi code here.

According to the provided API description the request should be set like this:

```
  request.Resource := 'pinpad/status';
  request.AddParameter('language', 'es');
  request.AddParameter('pinpad', '*');
```

Comment: Thank Uwe, That is what I am doing but it gives me the error of page not found, I don't know what else, I thought I might be missing something. the api says post, it gives me an error, if I put get it doesn't give me an error but it doesn't return anything

Comment: Well, that is what I can read from the docs. There is not much I can do anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help